# Calling a typedef'd struct to a function?

Tags: c, function, struct, malloc, typedef

I'm trying to call a structure to a function but I'm getting the error: 'course' undeclared
The error is in the hw3func program. I typedef'd my structure and malloc'd space for it inside of main, but I don't know what I need to make my function prototype or my function call to recognize the struct? Thank you for the help in advance!!

hw3.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hw3func.c"

int main(void)
{
    coursestruct *course = malloc(1*sizeof(coursestruct));
    studentstruct *student = malloc(1*sizeof(studentstruct));
    display();
    menu();

    return 0;
}
```

hw3.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*Start of prototypes*/
void display(void);
void menu(void);
void newcourse(int coursetotal, coursestruct *course);
void newstudent(int studenttotal);
/*End of prototypes*/



/*Start of initial struct declares*/
//  coursestruct *course = malloc(1 * sizeof(coursestruct));
//  studentstruct *student = malloc(1 * sizeof(studentstruct));
/*End of initial struct declares*/



/*Start of variables*/
    int coursetotal=0;
    int studenttotal=0;
/*End of variables*/
```

hw3struct.h:

```
typedef struct{
    char name[50];
    int id[4];
}coursestruct;

typedef struct{
    char name[20];
    int id[8];
}studentstruct;
```

hw3func.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hw3struct.h"
#include "hw3.h"

void display(void)
{}

void menu(void)
{
    int loop=0; /*Loop for the menu*/

    while(loop==0)
    {
        int option;

        printf("\n\n\nWelcome to the grade book! Select your option below.\n");
        printf("1=  Add a new course.\n");
        printf("2=  Add a new student.\n");
        printf("3=  Add a student to a course.\n");
        printf("4=  Add grades for a student in a course.\n");
        printf("5=  Print a list of all grades for a student in a course.\n");
        printf("6=  Print a list of all students in a course.\n");
        printf("7=  Compute the average for a student in a course.\n");
        printf("8=  Print a list of all courses.\n");
        printf("9=  Print a list of all students.\n");
        printf("10= Compute the average for a course.\n");
        printf("11= Store grade book to a disk file.\n");
        printf("12= Load grade book from a disk file.\n");
        printf("13= Exit grade book.\n");
        scanf("%d",&option);
        printf("\n\n\n");

        if(((option>0) && (option<14)))
        {
            switch(option)
            {
                case 1:
                    newcourse(coursetotal,course);
                    break;

                case 13:
                    loop=1;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Please input a number between 1-13.\n");
        }
    }
}

void newcourse(int coursetotal, coursestruct *course)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `coursestruct *course` inside `main`, so it is not directly accessible from other functions (like your `menu()` function).

You should do some reading on variable scope in C.

In this case, the proper fix is most likely to change your function declarations to something like

`void menu (coursestruct *course);`

Then call it from `main` as `menu(course);`. This allows the `menu` function access to the variable declared inside `main`.

Comment: Ah, damn you're right.. Is there an easier way to get around this like moving my menu to main?

Comment: Not really. You could declare your variables in a header file if you want them to be global, like you have done with `coursetotal` and `studentstruct`, but it's not really a good practice. The most accepted C coding style would say that you should pass any variable information to a function using arguments.